# Java - Changing boolean value in one class from another class

Tags: java

I am currently, for fun, making a pong game however I am currently stuck trying to get the value of my boolean "goingup" to a true state via the w key press. I have the boolean going up in my render class ,as well a int x and int y, and is set to false. In this class i draw a square , with x as int x and y as int y. In another class(Framemake.java) i have a key listener set to my Jframe. In this class i have the keylistener listening for the w key press and release. Here is where my problem arises: If the W key is pressed i want  it to change goingup to true and if its released i want it to change going up to false; this works fine but the problem is in my render class i have setup a timer , this is then started in the graphics method (not sure of the proper name). In the timers action performed i have set: if going up is true i want it to print out "going up is true- render". Here is the problem- even though going up is true because of the w key being pressed, the print is not printed onto the screen. (Thankyou for reading this, i needed you to fully understand whats going on- even though it may or may not be really obvious).

Here is the code:
Starter.java

```
public class Starter  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame(); 
    frame.Start(); 

}

}
```

Here is the Frame.java

```
public class Frame implements Runnable  {
Framemake r = new Framemake();

public void Start(){
    new Thread(this).start();//
}
public void run() {

    try {
        r.framemade();
        }
    catch (Exception e) { //
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }   

}

    }
```

Here is parts of Render.java as i was having troubles pasting into this post

```
public class Render extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

boolean goingup = false;
boolean goingdown = false;
int x = 0; //starting pos of x .
int y = 150;//starting pos of y
Timer tm = new Timer(7, this); //The timer is created



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  Framemake frames = new Framemake();
  super.paintComponent(g);
  tm.start();
  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 150);
  g.dispose();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //timer
  if(goingup){
    System.out.println("Going up is true- render");
    x++;//for example...
    repaint();
  }
}
```

Here is Framemake.java

```
public class Framemake implements KeyListener {
    int WIDTH = 500;
    int HEIGHT = 500;
    Render c = new Render();
    public void framemade() {
        System.out.println("Frame starting");
        //Frame is created here 
        Render render = new Render();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Animation");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window w = frame;
        w.addKeyListener(this);
        frame.add(render); //displays all graphics from render to the screen
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("Going up");
            c.goingup = true;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            System.out.println("Going down");
            c.goingdown = true;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("Up terminated");
            c.goingup = false;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            System.out.println("Down terminated");
            c.goingdown = false;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

I hope the question is clear here (Sorry if I have posted my code incorrectly), any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your class `Framemake`, you are not adding `Render c` to the `frame`. You are creating a local variable `render` instead.

To solve this, just delete the declaration of

```
Render render = new Render();
```

and add `c` to the `frame`:

```
frame.add(c);  // Instead of 'frame.add(render)'
```

**Summary:** Your method `framemade()` should look like this:

```
public void framemade()
{
    System.out.println("Frame starting");
    //Frame is created here 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("Animation");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Window w = frame;
    w.addKeyListener(this);
    frame.add(c); // Change this line
}
```

**Edit:**

I would also recommend you to read about why you should use private fields, getters and setters. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables).

Comment: Wow thankyou everyone for the very quick replies- Thanks for that it works perfectly now :).

Comment: @arunptl100 it looks like you already figured it out. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose, that your timer does not fire at all. You should probably start it only once, and not in the `paintComponent` Method. Since per default it will fire every 7 ms. 
Also add a line to see if the `actionPerformed` method actually fires:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ //timer
  System.out.println("Timer: actionPerformed");  
  if(goingup){
    System.out.println("Going up is true- render");
    x++;//for example...
    repaint();
  }
}
```

And why do you call `g.dispose();` in the `paintComponent` method? This method is called on each repaint. This will most likely lead to problems as well.

Comment: I tried that and it did work Timer: actionPerformed was repeated in the console suggesting the timer was running however you said i should start the timer elsewhere?

Comment: Ok good. Yes start it in the Constructor of the Render class. It only needs to be started once.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by simply adding a method like this and then call that:
    Public void setgoingup (boolean b) {
    this.goingup = b;
    }

Ps: i am tired and didn't read all the code - sorry if i missed anything ovious.

Comment: Good point, the OP really should make the attribute private and call a setter or method that does the desired thing. But this is not the root of his problems.

Comment: Okay, im sorry if i am wrong as i said above, i am a little bit tired and actually will go to sleep now. Just thought i could help a little bit :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (or notifier) pattern.

A very simple (and naive) example:
Create a class that will play the role of the observable, and
an interface with the role of the observer, along with its implementation
classes.
Hold a list to the observable class of the observer instances to inform when needed, and do it that way

(NOTICE: untested code):

```
public interface Observer{
  public void notify();
}

public class Observable{
  public List<Observer> _observers;

  public Observable(){
    _observers = new List<Observer>();
  }

  public void registerObserver(Observer obs){
     _observers.add(obs)
  }

  public void unregisterObserver(Observer obs){
    _observers.remove(obs);
  }

  public void notifyObservers{
    for(Observer obs : _observers) { 
       obs.notify();
    }
  }

}

public class SpecificObserver implements Observer{
  //Properties, Ctors etc

  public void notify(){
    //Do stuff when notified here
  }
}


and in your program:

public static void main(string[] args){

  Observable observable             = new Observable();
  SpecificObserver specificObserver = new SpecificObserver();
  //More init code here

  observable.registerObserver(specificObserver);
  //Etc...

  //read input
  string str = YourClass.GetInput();

  while(!str.Equals("EndString"))
  {
    if(str.Equals("SpecificInput"))
    {
      observable.notifyObservers();
    }
    str = YourClass.GetInput();
  }

}
```

Of course, you can modify it to your needs (add arguments to the `Notify` method, run the loop to another thread that checks the condition you want rather than the input etc)